# Is .container-fluid/.container used only for grid system?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have just started learning bootstrap from https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp website. In the website it is stated that `.container-fluid` and `.container` classes have to be used for grid system i.e. only when we have rows and columns. But all the code snippets of the "navigation bar" section on that website uses `.container-fluid` class even when no rows and columns are used.The navigation bars are created using `ul`(unordered list). Following is one example:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

So here is the question:Where can I use `.container-fluid` class? Can I apply `.container-fluid` to the complete body of my page?

Comment: You can use `.container-fluid` anytime you need a full width container spanning the entire width of your viewport.

Comment: By viewport did you mean viewpoint?

Comment: Viewport is the user's visible area of the webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Bootstrap [site](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container), this is the intended usage of a 'container':

> Bootstrap requires a containing element **to wrap site contents** and **house our grid system**. You may choose one of two containers to use in
>   your projects. Note that, due to padding and more, neither container
>   is nestable.
>
> Use .container for a responsive fixed width container.
>
> Use .container-fluid for a full width container, spanning the entire
>   width of your viewport.

So, whether you are intentionally using it for the grid system or not you can still use one or the other as a container for your page contents (or a portion thereof).  You'll get the following CSS rules either way, with some differing rules for child elements (download the source and peruse it to see):

```
    [both container and container-fluid] {
      padding-right: 15px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      width: [for container this is based on media query]
    }
    :before,:after {
      display: table;
      content: " ";
    }
    :after {
      clear: both;
    }
```

Typical usage would be on a div inside the body, not on the body itself, from my experience.